# ViewPager and FrameLayout issue with Recyclerview

Tags: android-viewpager, android-framelayout

i am facing Problem to display recycler view in FrameLayout Fragment.
in activity.xml(MainActivity.java) define viewpager and full screen FrameLayout.
when i run app first time, i am calling fragment inside framelayout which have RecyclerView without setting adapter of Viewpager but my recyclerview not display anything first time.
After closing fragment i am setting viewpager adapter.
one's pager adapter set and again go to same fragment then recyclerview  display perfectlly.
please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: ok i got solution, with my self.. problem with edittext focus change listener.